# Какие члены будут в предложении "Яблок кот наплакал"?

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения

Какие члены будут в предложении "Яблок кот наплакал"?

Comment: Если вам дан ответ, который помог, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 1):

Кот наплакал — идиома (фразеологизм), она целиком является сказуемым (сравните с другой идиоматизированной (фразеологизированной) конструкцией: *Денег — хоть отбавляй!*).

Яблок — дополнение (*кот наплакал (=мало)* **чего?** *яблок*).